# Yocto - using extensible SDK with multilib

Tags: architecture, sdk, yocto

#### Short version:

I have an 64 bit Yocto Raspberry build with a piece of 32 bit software with multilib. The goal is now to be able to use the eSDK to build 32 bit software for that system. After building and installing the eSDK there are even two files `environment-setup-aarch64-poky-linux` and `environment-setup-armv7ve-vfp-pokymllib32-linux-gnueabi`. After sourcing the 32bit `armv7ve` environment file `devtool` is still building my software as 64 bit. Why doesn't it work?

#### Long version:

The **multilib definition** in my `local` config looks like this:

```
require conf/multilib.conf
MULTILIBS = "multilib:lib32"
DEFAULTTUNE_virtclass-multilib-lib32 = "armv7ve"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append_raspberrypi3-64 = " lib32-software-dummy"
```

The `software-dummy` "hello world" project builds fine in 32 bit.

**Now on to the eSDK:**
The `environment-setup-armv7ve-vfp-pokymllib32-linux-gnueabi` actually didn't work out of the box, I needed to add the bottom of `environment-setup-aarch64-poky-linux` to `environment-setup-armv7ve-vfp-pokymllib32-linux-gnueabi`, so `devtool` is found.

This part was missing from the `armv7ve` environment file:

```sh
. /workdir/sdk/rpi/buildtools/environment-setup*
export OE_SKIP_SDK_CHECK=1
export DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE=/workdir/sdk/rpi/tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi3-64
export PATH=/workdir/sdk/rpi/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin:$PATH
printf 'SDK environment now set up; additionally you may now run devtool to perform development tasks.
Run devtool --help for further details.
'
(which bitbake > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo 'WARNING: attempting to use the extensible SDK in an environment set up to run bitbake - this may lead to unexpected results. Please source this script in a new shell session instead.') || true
```

Otherwise the environment files look alright I believe.

Eg. in `environment-setup-aarch64-poky-linux` we have:

```sh
export CC="aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export CXX="aarch64-poky-linux-g++  --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
…
export ARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-poky-linux-
```

while in `environment-setup-armv7ve-vfp-pokymllib32-linux-gnueabi`:

```sh
export CC="arm-pokymllib32-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7ve -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export CXX="arm-pokymllib32-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7ve -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
…
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-pokymllib32-linux-gnueabi-
```

After sourcing the `armv7ve` environment file, building the software I added with devtool, it's still building in 64 bit. Looking at the `run.do_install` logfile I see this:

```sh
export AR="aarch64-poky-linux-ar"
export AS="aarch64-poky-linux-as "
…
export CC="aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/workdir/sdk/rpi/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/cmake-test/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot"
…
export CCLD="aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/workdir/sdk/rpi/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/cmake-test/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot"
```

for some reason it's all 64 bit in there and I don't know where this comes from. The `armv7ve` environment file also has `/workdir/sdk/rpi/tmp/sysroots/x86_64/usr/bin/arm-pokymllib32-linux-gnueabi` in it's PATH, where the 32 bit compilers seem to live.

Thank you for any help!